# Day missing from Date

Tags: windows, windows-7, batch-file, dos

See Batch code below, it show a date and time but the day is missing. How to fix this?

code:

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set dt=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:." %%a in ('echo %time%') do (set tm=%%a.%%b)
set bkupfilename=%1 %dt% %tm%.bak
echo Backing up to file: %bkupfilename%
```

Output:

```
C:\wamp>backup.bat
Backing up to file:  -08-2011 15.49.bak
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when parsing output of system commands like `date /t`, the system locale is very important.

the first line of the script issues the command `date /t` and parses its output. it splits the string at specified delimiters, which are the space  (hence the space before the end `"`) and the slash `/`. it then takes the 2nd to 4th items found and assign them to variables `%a`, `%b` and `%c`.

if you type `date /t` on your console you will see the output and understand why the script is not working...

- the system on which this command was written used american date format (month-day-year),
- on my system, which uses european date format (day-month-year), the script works but invert the month and the day.

i suppose that on your system, the ouput of the `date /t` command is different, due to your system locale settings. you will have to modify your script in order to comply to these settings.

(also, keep in mind that this kind of script is not portable: another user using another locale will encounter the same kind of problems)

Comment: Thank you, thats explained it.  The output of `date /t` is 25/08/2011

Answer (score 1):

You are using delimiters that cut off the day on the first line (2-4).

To fix it just change the first line to have 1 as the start:

```
For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set dt=%%c-%%a-%%b)
```

Complete code:

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set dt=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:." %%a in ('echo %time%') do (set tm=%%a.%%b)
set bkupfilename=%1 %dt% %tm%.bak
echo Backing up to file: %bkupfilename%
```

Note: you can change it also to 1-3 as there is no need for 1-4 but it will work all the same.